# get read ENOTCONN error on windows 10 when calling a docker api

Tags: node.js, docker, sockets

I' trying to [start an exec instance](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.37/#operation/ExecStart) of my docker image through my node project with code below:

```
return axios.post(host + `/exec/${id}/start`, { Detach: false, Tty: true }, 
{ responseType: 'stream' })
  .then(function () {
     let stream = response.data
     let socket = stream.socket
     socket.on('data', (data: string) => {
     process.stdin.pause()
      if (!firstLine)
         process.stdout.write(data)
      firstLine = false
      process.stdin.resume()
     })

    process.stdout.on('data', i => {
      socket.write(i.toString())
      if (i == DetachKey) {
        rl.emit('SIGINT')
      }
   })

   rl.on('SIGINT', function () {
     // stop input
     socket.emit('end')
     process.stdin.pause()
     process.stdout.write(exec_exit_msg)
     process.exit(0)
  })
})
```

On Linux(Ubuntu & Mint) everything is OK, but when I test my code on windows 10 I get the error blow:

```
Error: read ENOTCONN
at WriteStream.Socket._read (net.js:529:20)
at WriteStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:453:10)
at resume_ (_stream_readable.js:929:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

My node version is v10.15.3 (using nvm).

It seems that there is something wrong with the socket connection. I searched a lot but could not figured out how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Below Part of Code makes the error. I removed it and change the code a little
But I don't know why it was ok in ubuntu

```
process.stdout.on('data', i => {
  socket.write(i.toString())
  if (i == DetachKey) {
    rl.emit('SIGINT')
  }
```

})